# Redirecting .com to .com.au breaks .com.au with too many redirects, also using change to naked domain from www. using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

my domain breaktagdigital.com needs to be redirected to https://breaktagdigital.com.au I already have this setup in my rewrite rules which does not seem to be redirecting the URL or any other pages, which it is also not allowing me to do within wordpress, force secure is on within cloudflare and I just turned it off in Ithemes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.breaktagdigital.com.au [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^breaktagdigital.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://breaktagdigital.com.au/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

if I add anything to this to try redirect breaktagdigital.com any further it breaks .com.au help please?
Should I be putting another if module in between wordpress and ithemes??

Answer (score 1):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. This will redirect from www/non-www yoursite.com TO yoursite.com.au site. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(breaktagdigital\.com) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.au%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```